# Matplotlib- meshgrid

Tags: python, matplotlib, pde

I would like to make a surface plot for the solution of a grid. My domain ranges from [-1, 1] in both x and y directions. I understand that I need to provide 2D arrays to plot_surface(x,y,z) for x and y. However, I do not understand how to arrange this for z.

To make things clearer, say I take a grid spacing of 3 points in each direction. I end up getting [-1, 0, 1] and [-1, 0, 1] in both the x and y directions respectively. This gives me 9 points where I need to evaluate for z. Here's what I wrote:

```
x = np.linspace(-1,1, 3)
y = np.linspace(-1,1, 3)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
# Remaining code uses plot_surface(X, Y, Z_approx)
#
```

Each X and Y are 2D arrays, of length 3 each. However, my Z "approximation" has a length of 9. How do I then plot this together?

Here's how the grid would look!

> *(-1,1) ____ *(0,1) ____ *(1,1)
>
> *(-1,0) ____ *(0,0) ____ *(1,0)
>
> *(-1,-1)____ *(0,-1)____ *(1,-1)

Comment: Hint: `Z = np.sin(3*np.sqrt(X*X+Y*Y)); print Z`

Comment: @gboffi Well that's the problem! I already have a "Z". I'm not trying to plot an exact solution. So, the function you just mentioned in terms of Z does not exist for me. I have values of Z obtained by an approximate solution at the various grid points, and that gives len(Z) = 9. However, len(X) and len(Y) are 3 each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a bit tough to provide an answer when we don't know what your `z` matrix is, so here are my two best guesses:

1. `z` is a 1x9 (or 9x1) vector, in which case it should be reshaped to a 3x3 matrix using the [`np.reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) command.

e.g.

```
Z = np.reshape(Z_approx, (3, 3))
```

or

2. `z` is a 9x9 matrix, in which case I would just make `x` and `y` 9x9 matrices instead of 3x3 using this small change.

e.g.

```
x = np.linspace(-1,1, 9)
y = np.linspace(-1,1, 9)
```

Hope that helps, or maybe you can let us know more about your `z` matrix.

Comment: That works! Z was a 9x1 matrix. Thank you! I still don't understand how 2D arrays facilitate the whole process. Could you possibly explain this?

Comment: To plot a 3D figure, such as a surface plot, each point in space needs to be defined by 3 points, your x, y, and z.  By using 2D vectors (which you illustrated very well in the OP), you provide a definition of the `x`, `y`, and `z` values for each point in space.  `X` and `Y` in the OP are your "grid", and `Z` from my solution is "elevation".  Each value in your 3x3 `Z` matches one of the coordinates in your `X` and `Y` matrices.

There are several ways to explain it; feel free to message me if you'd like additional guidance.

Comment: This does make sense to me. I didn't understand why we were using mesh grid for it. I suppose it creates the right amount of "combinations" of x and y to be plotted along with z. I hope that is correct to some extent at least :)

Comment: In a 2D graph, you have 1 `x` value for every 1 `y` value.  In a 3D graph, each `x` value is paired with multiple `y` values.  In your case, `x=-1` is paired with `y=-1`, `y=0`, and `y=1`.  The same is true for `x=0` and `x=1`.  `Meshgrid` essentially gives you matrices from vectors so that these pairings are explicitly defined.  If you have two row vectors `x` and `y` that define the range of your plot, then the only spaces defined in your plot are the pairs of values from your row vectors.  By creating 2D matrices, you explicitly state the points at which your function (`z`) is defined.